# VS code put space everywhere after formating

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, sass, format

well I am new in coding but today was disaster!
I am trying using format code in VS (file is scss). But after formating it put spaces everywhere literally. Honestly I am tired of all day coding and this happend! It looks like this:

```
.u - center - text {
text - align : center !important; }
```

or this is nightmare! spaces between number and %

```
@media(max - width : 600 px) {
    font - size : 50 %;
}
```

another example is this:

```
*, *:: after, *:: before {
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
box - sizing : inherit;
}
```

Well I am gonna drink some wine with hope someone know what is possible to do with this. I could not find it.
Bless to the person who knows because I have no idea! OMG spaces between font - size.

Answer (score 0):

So today I tryied this. Unistall all format extensions in VS Code. Then uninstall VS code itself. After I open my PC file and delete deleted extensions from PC file.
After this I installed back VS Code and all needed extensions back.
And voilá. It is good now.
I have no idea what was bad, but if you are not sure what is bad in your extensions it is not enough just uninstall it but you need check it and delete it from PC file.
This video can help.

https://youtu.be/OR3yOvea6tY